# Can't access UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, django, http, http-status-code-404

UPDATE([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nhnq.png) I have added backslash to the url and new error comes out )
My idea is to have Teachers and Students and I want my Teachers to have the ability to edit quizzes for the students for some reason when I try to acces the QuizUpdateView via other ListView it gives me 404 Not Found [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Ohn.png)
So I want to edit my quiz with this view:

```
class QuizUpdateView(views.UpdateView):
model = Quiz
fields = ('name', 'subject', )
context_object_name = 'quiz'
template_name = 'classroom/quiz_update.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['questions'] = 
self.get_object().questions.annotate(answers_count=Count('answers'))
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.quizzes.all()

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('quizzes')
```

I have int:pk in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = (
path('register', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
path('register/student', StudentRegisterView.as_view(), name='register student'),
path('register/register', TeacherRegisterView.as_view(), name='register teacher'),
path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
path('quizzes', QuizListView.as_view(), name='quizzes'),
path('quiz/create', QuizCreateView.as_view(), name='create quiz'),
path('quiz/update/<int:pk>', QuizUpdateView.as_view(), name='update quiz'),
)
```

I have the quiz.pk in templates as well(I tried with quiz.id, same result)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_content %}
{% include 'classroom/student_header.html' with active='new' %}
<div class="card">
    <table class="table mb-0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quiz</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Length</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for quiz in quizzes %}
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.name }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.subject.get_html_badge }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle"> questions</td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    {% if request.user.type == 'Student' %}
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Start quiz</a>
                    {% elif request.user.type == 'Teacher' %}
                        
                        <a href="{% url 'update quiz' quiz.pk %}" class="btn btn- 
         warning">Edit quiz</a>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">Delete quiz</a>
                        
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% empty %}
            <tr>
                <td class="bg-light text-center font-italic" colspan="4">No exam 
                matching your interests right
                    now.
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the model

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(UniversityUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='quizzes')
name = models.CharField(max_length=QUIZ_NAME_MAX_LENGTH, unique=True)
subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='quizzes')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And here is the template I am using for the UpdateView:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_content %}
<h2 class="mb-3">
    {{ quiz.name }}
    <a href="{% url 'teachers:quiz_results' quiz.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary float- 
right">View results</a>
</h2>
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-12">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'update quiz' quiz.pk %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
            <a href="{% url 'quizzes' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
 role="button">Nevermind</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger float-right">Delete</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <strong>Questions</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <strong>Answers</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-formset">
        {% for question in questions %}
            <div class="list-group-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <a href="">{{ question.text }}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        {{ question.answers_count }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            <div class="list-group-item text-center">
                <p class="text-muted font-italic mb-0">You haven't created any 
  questions yet. Go ahead and <a
                        href="">add the first question</a>.</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add question</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

If you have any ideas why this is happening please leave a comment thanks! :)

Comment: What happens if you add a `/` at the end of your url pattern, i.e. instead of `'quiz/update/<int:pk>'` try `'quiz/update/<int:pk>/'`. In your error it shows that the request url has a trailing slash.

Comment: Your url definition is `quiz/update/<int:pk>` but the url you are accessing is `quiz/update/<int:pk>/` notice the additional slash at the end, I think you need to decide if you want slashes at the end of all your URLs (default django) or if you want to re-configure django to disable the slashes at the end of your url

Comment: I have added it but it comes different error now posted the new screenshot at beginning of the question

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but is that class you inherit from is right?
try to import :

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdatView

class QuizUpdateView(UpdateView):
```

Comment: I use
<  from django.views import generic as views >